# What's the name of the fallacy for evaluating a complex issue by extrapolating only one variable?

Tags: meaning

For e.g

"He is a man - therefore he has male privilege".

Yet the man could be in a wheelchair, suicidal, have a terminal illness. All of which get overlooked if you only look through the prism of just "gender".  After evaluation of more than one variable, it is apparent he has inferior privilege.

What is the name for this fallacy of evaluating using only a limited amount of variables?

Answer (score 2):

Social commentary aside, this would be a "sweeping generalization". It assumes that what may be true about the group as a whole must also be true about the individual -- thus "sweeping" the individual along with the rest of the group.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be the **ecological fallacy**.

> *Ecological fallacy* – where inferences about the nature of specific individuals are based solely upon aggregate statistics collected for
>   the group to which those individuals belong.

[[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fallacies)]